# chatGPT regulation & content mills

Tags: discussion

Should the site have any policy w.r.t. chatGPT and similar language prediction tools?

1. Are chatGPT written questions acceptable?
2. Are chatGPT written answers acceptable?
3. Are questions asking for an overview of a longish chatGPT answer on-topic?

   [Example 1](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/54756/i-asked-chatgpt-to-explain-pairwise-relationships-between-economic-variables), [example 2](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/54757/i-asked-chat-gpt-to-ask-chatgpt)
4. Are chatGPT written questions acceptable on meta?

Answer (score 1):

> Are chatGPT written questions acceptable? Are chatGPT written answers acceptable? Are chatGPT written questions acceptable on meta?

No, in fact recently there was recently even online meeting between us mods and SE where it was said that this should be discouraged, and we already suspended several accounts on this network which were discovered to be just fully chatGPT generated answers however, we had no such question yet.

So if someone just copy pasts chatGPT generated text as answer or question that is already effectively disallowed.

> Are questions asking for an overview of a longish chatGPT answer on-topic?

I don't see any reason why this should be against the rules. The question itself is not generated by chatGPT it is question about accuracy of some chatGTP generated text.

This is not the same as posting question generated by chatGTP without explanation, or copy pasting answer. We allow questions about non-academic explainers, I don't see how this is principally different.

The question has a problem that it asks multiple questions at the same time, and being too broad, but these two rules on this site were never strongly enforced (in a sense you will find very little such questions closed by moderators)  and we have here many such questions. In past we almost always elected to let users decide what is broad or not too broad for the site.

We could start enforcing this rule more strictly if there is community desire to do that. However, we recently lowered the votes needed to close question just to 3 so even on smaller stack if there is desire to close such questions its easy to do by users.

For these sort of questions I think just regular rules should apply e.g. is the question off topic? Is it a duplicate question? Is it too broad? etc

Comment: Isn't this a contentious issue that led to the strike many moderators on this network partake in?

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker it became contentious issue after the original policy was supposed to be reversed there were some posts about it on mod stack exchange regular users can’t see. Some CMs argued that detection algorithms mods use to see if something is Chat GPT generated are somehow discriminating against minorities so there was supposed to be change in policy where people should not use these and you can only suspend if you can make sure it is chat GPT other ways which is extremely difficult without someone making it super obvious. However as far as I know if people know something is

Comment: Chat GPT generated it’s still banable, although I don’t follow these arguments as closely as other mods because I don’t like to get involved in all the drama

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure, but I have the impression that the following  answer is chatGPT generated

[How is potential experience usually measured in the Mincer equation?](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/53650/how-is-potential-experience-usually-measured-in-the-mincer-equation/55383#55383)

Also because I saw the profile of the answerer, and it contains a link to an online casino

<link removed>

so that the answer perhaps is actually spam aimed at advertising that online casino.